# Streaming with a-frame videosphere on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari, aframe

I'm using an a-frame videosphere to display a rather large mp4 video file (70 MB). Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari (both mobile and desktop) the video won't start to render before the whole video file has been fully loaded. It doesn't seem to be able to stream while loading. When I embed the source video file directly as an html5 video, Safari is able to buffer the video. Therefore I think the reason must be some a-frame internal stuff..
Did anybody else also encounter this problem and maybe has an idea what to do about it?

I hope somebody can help, thank you in advance!

PS.: a-frame version 0.7.0, Safari 11.0 (Desktop)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason in a-frame and submitted a pull-request (https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/3089).

A-frame checks whether the referenced file is an image or not by setting the src on an Image-object and listening for 'load' and 'error' events. Safari does not fire those events until the source file is fully loaded, and only after that the video is displayed. I replaced the image check with a xhr head request and checking for the content-type.